# How to get different node children from different parents using Xpath (or what to use instead)?

Tags: java, android, xml, xpath

The XML file I am working with is an online strem and is structured like this:
Edited:

```
<forecasts>
    <forecast  date="yyyy-mm-dd">
        <night>
            <place>
               <name>Chicago</name>
                 <tempmin>9</tempmin>
            </place>
            <place>
                <name>Denver</name>
                <tempmin>11</tempmin>
            </place>
        </night>
        <day>
            <place>
                <name>Chicago</name>
                <tempmax>19</tempmax>
            </place>
            <place>
                <name>Denver</name>
                <tempmax>20</tempmax>
            </place>
        </day>
    </forecast>
</forecasts>
```

So in the main activity there's a ListView, which is to **display the names** of all the places (cities).
What it's supposed to do when the user has made a selection:

- start a new activity in which the program will
- show the **name** of the place
- show the **tempmin** and **tempmax** values of the user made selection

Now, what I cannot figure out, is how to get, the tempmin and tempmax values of Denver (for instance) and show them both to user. Below is the code snippet to list all the places

```
ArrayList<String> mPlaces = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        getPlaceList();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: " + ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mPlaces);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        ListView lv = getListView();

    private void getPlaceList() throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.this.url/thisurl/xml/forecast.php");
        InputSource inputSrc = new InputSource(url.openStream());
        // query XPath instance, this is the parser
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        String names = "//night/place/name";
        NodeList nameList = (NodeList)xpath.evaluate(names, inputSrc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        if(nameList != null && nameList.getLength() > 0) {
        mPlaces.clear();
        int len = nameList.getLength();

        for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            // query value
            Node node = nameList.item(i);
            mPlaces.add(node.getTextContent());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your requirement correctly you want to get a certain place at either the `<day/>` or `<night/>` element. Lets assume you want to get the second `<place/>` element you can do so by using the following XPath:

```
/forecast/(day, night)/place[2]
```

If you have more parent elements and you want simply all of them you could also do

```
/forecast/*/place[2]
```

If you know the selected name instead of the position you can use it to select the place element:

```
/forecast/(day, night)/place[name = "Place 2"]
```

Comment: I need to use both the night (tempmin) and day (tempmax) elements of a place selected.

Comment: So this should work for you. If you still have any problems, please describe them.

Comment: This is looking good. But I'm not quite sure it's working for me. Tried /forecast/(night, day)/place/name in main activity, just to put the names into ListView in a more sophisticated way - no success. TransformerException: A location step was expected @dirkk

Comment: Could be that your XPath processor does not support this syntax. You might want to try using the union operator, i.e. `/forecast/day/place[2] | /forecast/night/place[2]`

Comment: This again will return the same place twice. And the main goal is to get the tempmin and tempmax values of the place user has selected. @dirkk

Comment: It certainly will not. As you can see, the XPath in the first part uses the day element, in the second part the night element. This will never return the same element. Please also clarify your question. Please give example output for your example input. It is unclear to me how you want to identify the place (based on the name? based on the position?) and what your problem is using tempmin/tempmax. This should be a simple axis step

Answer (score -1):

Do you control the structure of your XML? If so, I would suggest to change it to

```
<forecast>
    <place>
        <name></name>
        <tempmin></tempmin>
        <tempmax></tempmax>
    </place>
    <place>
        <name></name>
        <tempmin></tempmin>
        <tempmax></tempmax>
    </place>
</forecast>
```

This is smaller and has all the information (it night/day doesn't matter as you only keep one piece of info for each). If you need night/day, you can add that with a small tweak. XML stores data hierarchically, so if you make sure to follow that, processing it is much easier.

Edit: so the XML input is fixed; you can use XPATH expressions like the following to get your min/max temperature knowing the name of a place:

```
//place[name="place1"]/tempmin
//place[name="place1"]/tempmax
```

That being said might not be very performant depending on the size of the XML file... You might be better processing it on the fly and transforming it into Java objects which will speed up the lookups...

Comment: No, I forgot to mention that the XML was an online stream coming from URL. I'll add this addition to my question.

Comment: Your answer is just plain wrong. First of all, it is never good advice to simply change the XML input. Even if it would be changeable there might be very good reasons for the XML being like it is. In this case, it is rather obvious that there is a semantic difference between day and night forecasts. Your last sentence is much worse, because it could even be harmful. It is certainly not faster to transform a complete XML document into Java objects instead of using a decent XPath processor.